# How do I create a boto3 sessions that both uses a local AWS profile (by name), and assumes a AWS IAM role?

Tags: boto3, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager, botocore, aws-roles

This is **not** a duplicate.  I have searched and could not find an exact match for this.

---

I have Python code running on my **local machine**.

I want to connect to AWS for the purpose of pulling a secret from **AWS Secrets Management**

---

On my local machine **$HOME/.aws/config** file, I have a profile configured.

```
[profile my-profile]
...
```

---

The profile is setup with the region, AWS account ID etc.

This is a known working profile that will connect to AWS.

---

I have configured an **AWS IAM Role** that is configured to restrict access to a secret stored in AWS Secrets.

---

On my local machine, in python code, I want to create a **boto3 session** and **client** that will:

1. use the AWS local profile settings to connect to AWS
2. and connect assuming the IAM role

so I can then pull the secret.

---

How do I create this **boto3 session** / **client** with this criteria?

I am not finding documentation on how to use both (local AWS profile by name and also assume AWS IAM role) for the specific purpose of pulling from AWS Secrets Management.

---

If anyone has actually done this, it would be greatly appreciated if code could be shared.

---

I have pulling a secret not assuming the role working fine on pulling a secret that is not restricted by a role.

Now I have created another secret restricted by a role and I cannot get this to work.

Comment: You talk about assuming role, do you mean an actual `aws sts assume-role` call?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to choose an AWS profile when using boto3 to connect to CloudFront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378422/how-to-choose-an-aws-profile-when-using-boto3-to-connect-to-cloudfront)

Comment: And then [AWS: Boto3: AssumeRole example which includes role usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44171849/aws-boto3-assumerole-example-which-includes-role-usage) if you actually talk about assuming other roles.

Comment: Thank you, but **none** of these help answer the question.  I need to use 1. a local named AWS profile 2. AND also assume an AWS IAM role to access AWS secrets.

Comment: Then the two answers answer that perfectly, the first tells you how to use a profile, the second one tells you how to assume a role. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @luk2302 - It shows how to use them seperately.  It does not show how to use them together in one unified session and client.

Neither are a solution that get me there.  challenge: If you think it works, code it up and try.  Just do it.  Apparently this is a big hole in boto3 and it's not possible.

Comment: You seem to not understand how boto (sessions / credentials) works. You have one session based on the profile (or ANYTHING else (ec2 metadata / access+secret, ...), does not matter a single bit), then call `assume-role` with that session, get credentials and create a new session object based on those credentials. And then you use that new session for whatever. That is how sessions work and how they are supposed to work.

Comment: right, you are right.  I don't understand how sessions and credentials work.  That's why I am posting here asking the question.  If you do, then please provide an actual working example to educate.  I do not understand why I need to 'get credentials' when the credentials are provided in the local profile in $HOME/.aws/config and $HOME/.aws/credentials - that makes no sense to me if it is provided in the session by providing the profile name.  And if I already have a session with credentials, why do I need to create another session (with credentials), as you are suggesting here.  Code talks

Comment: Actually, there's an easier way to do this: [Boto3: How to assume IAM Role to access other account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71359754/174777)

Answer (score -1):

To call `AssumeRole()`, you first need a set of credentials that have permission to call `AssumeRole`. These credentials will come from your `~/.aws/credentials` file (optionally using a specific **profile**).

In response to an `AssumeRole()` call, AWS will return:

```json
{
    'Credentials': {
        'AccessKeyId': 'string',
        'SecretAccessKey': 'string',
        'SessionToken': 'string',
        'Expiration': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
    },
    'AssumedRoleUser': {
        'AssumedRoleId': 'string',
        'Arn': 'string'
    },
    'PackedPolicySize': 123,
    'SourceIdentity': 'string'
}
```

This includes a **different set of credentials** that are associated with the IAM Role (instead of your IAM User). You must then use *these* credentials when making an API call 'as the assumed role'.

Think of it as **entering a house with a front-door key** then going to a table and **picking up a car key**. You can use the car key to drive the car that is outside the house, but you can't drive the car with the house key you used to *enter* the house.

- House key = Your IAM User credentials
- Picking up a Car key = Calling `AssumeRole()` and getting a new set of credentials (a new key)

You need to use the second set of credentials to drive the car.

Comment: This piece of information is helpful.  I am still in need of boto3 code that will accomplish the task.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually, there's an easier way to do this: [Boto3: How to assume IAM Role to access other account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71359754/174777)